# devtool upgrade ERROR: recipe is already in your workspace

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I use "devtool" of Yocto, eSDK to create the recipe.

I'd like to upgrade it the source code to build newer version package.

So I did update SRCREV and PV = "0.1+git${SRCPV}" variable but no different source tree is fetched (where SRCREV is pointing to).

I do following

> devtool upgrade myrecipe --srcrev 82a02d8585d262d6ab2d9dc335ed2231dc2d7f06

I am getting error

> ERROR: recipe is already in your workspace

How to correctly upgrade recipe with devtool (eSDK)?

Thanks for help.

Prior to this:

1. installed the extensible SDK
2. created generic recipe by

> ```
> devtool add myrecipe "specified URI to fetch from"
> ```

3. run build command

> ```
> devtool build myrecipe
> ```

4. deploy it to target

> ```
> devtool deploy-target -s myrecipe root@192.168.15.241
> ```

5. after that the package is on target and everything seems OK.

Now I would need to upgrade recipe to the new version of software. I use `devtool upgrade` for that as described above and I have run into issue.

Comment: Could you please describe what you did prior to this? The error you mention indicates you've done something to put myrecipe in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

In a workflow starting with `devtool add`, `devtool upgrade` is not intended to be used. If you want to change to build a different revision in this context you would instead simply check it out in the repository (which would be under workspace/sources/myrecipe) using `git checkout`. When you later come to do `devtool finish`, devtool should update your recipe to check this revision out when building the recipe normally.

Comment: if update SRCREV and PV has no effect on code revision?

Comment: what's the workflow for devtool upgrade thhough? Should I use existing recipes to build image with? Is there any example on use of detool upgrade?